# (id=25) near variable debug info in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

What means (id=40) in Eclipse near variable PacketNr watch info? What this id is used for?

[image: id=40]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID is just an arbitary number assigned by the eclipse debugger. This can be used to determine whether two references are pointing to the same object or not. So two references to the same object should have a same id. This can be a help while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

That is nothing but a `unique object-id, eclipse assigns to objects.`

It will just help in debugging.